# Calculating 90th Percentile between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have a table with 4 columns out of which 2 are date columns I need find the difference between those and then find the 90th percentile

Table A

```
ID,Name,Start_Date,End_Date
1,abc,04/15/2014,04/16/2014 
2,xyz,05/13/2014,05/13/2014 
3,afd,05/13/2014,05/14/2014 
4,rfd,05/15/2014,05/16/2014 
5,grr,06/15/2014,06/16/2014
```

Any help or pointers are highly appreciated

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: 90th percentile for each row or the the entire data-set?

Comment: thank you @GordonLinoff I need either for sql or postgresql

Comment: 90th from top or bottom?  desired output would be helpful

Comment: @JohnCappelletti it is for whole data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @Table table (ID int, Name varchar(50),Start_Date Date,End_Date Date)
Insert into @Table values
(1,'abc','04/15/2014','04/16/2014'),
(2,'xyz','05/13/2014','05/13/2014'),
(3,'afd','05/13/2014','05/14/2014'), 
(4,'rfd','05/15/2014','05/16/2014'), 
(5,'grr','06/15/2014','06/16/2014') 

Select DateR1=min(Start_Date),DateR2=DateAdd(DD,DateDiff(DD,min(Start_Date),max(End_Date))*.9,min(Start_Date))
 From  @Table
```

Returns

```
DateR1      DateR2
2014-04-15  2014-06-09
```

So to return the records

```
Select A.* 
 From  @Table A
 Join (Select DateR1=min(Start_Date),DateR2=DateAdd(DD,DateDiff(DD,min(Start_Date),max(End_Date))*.9,min(Start_Date)) From  @Table) B
   on (A.Start_Date Between B.DateR1 and B.DateR2)
```

Returns 4 of the 5 original records

```
ID  Name    Start_Date  End_Date
1   abc     2014-04-15  2014-04-16
2   xyz     2014-05-13  2014-05-13
3   afd     2014-05-13  2014-05-14
4   rfd     2014-05-15  2014-05-16
```

Comment: what are dateR1 and dateR2 I need id and name to be displayed

Comment: @Zack DateR1/R2 are the date ranges which represent the 90th percentile of dates within your data-set.   A desired result would have been helpful

Comment: @Zack Updated my answer to include a second query

Comment: Shocking that an answer written in T-SQL would be accepted for a question tagged Postgres -- the OP can accept whichever answer s/he wants to, of course, but it is very surprising when something like this occurs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Originally I saw the SQL Server tag.   I am very sure that you are in no danger of losing your #1 rank.  Don't kid yourself... we watch and quietly hope you'll take a nap one day.  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . The comment wasn't directed at you.  Your answer is good and correct; it is the question that is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`percentile_disc()` or `percentile_cont()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select percentile_cont(0.90) within group (order by date_end - date_start)
from t;
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply but can is there any way to use in sql server 2008

Comment: @Zack . . .You can ask another question and tag it with the correct database.  Changing this question is rude because it already has answers and such changes could invalidate answers -- drawing downvotes.